# This short PHP code works only in Firefox?

Tags: php, wordpress

My question is about WordPress, but it might just be a general PHP question...I'm trying to make a custom download button for my single posts, so I added the following code in my single.php

```
<div id="downloadbutton">
  <?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, "download_link", $single = true) != ""){ ?>
  <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "download_link", $single = true); ?>"<img src="example.png" border="0"></a>
  <?php } ?>
</div>
```

For some reason, the download button shows up only in Firefox browser, but not in Chrome or IE...

Any tips?

Comment: what get_post_meta function do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the `<a>` tag:

```
  <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "download_link", $single = true); ?>"><img src="example.png" border="0"></a>
```